# Error with BundleTable.EnableOptimizations when true

Tags: optimization, bundle

I'm having a problem with the BundleTable.EnableOptimizations, when it's fake the website loads normally, but when it's true the site does not seem to load CSS files, I've looked for some solutions like

> bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/Content/css")

always start with" ~ / bundles ", I also saw cases of adding some tags in web.config, and none worked.

My site uses language on the route, I do not know if this can be a problem.

> Routes.MapRoute (Name: "DefaultLang", Url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", Defaults: new {controller = "Menu", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
>                );